# Dynamically select dropdown based on another dropdown in nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a collection 'Country' in the mongodb. 
Mongoose schema is as follows:

```
{ 
id: number field(autoincrement by 1), 
short: //stores IN, US, UK 
Name: //stores India, United States, United Kingdom 
}
```

for ex:

```
{_id: objectId, id: 1, short: "IN", name: "India"}
{_id: objectId, id: 2, short: "US", name: "United States"}
{_id: objectId, id: 3, short: "UK", name: "United Kingdom"}
```

In UI, I have two dropdowns: short and country.
short dropdown is binded to short and country dropdown is binded to name field of country collection.

Now my requirement is: when I select 'IN' in short dropdown, 'India' should be selected in country dropdown.

Can anybody please suggest how to proceed with this requirement.

Thanks

Comment: Please show the relevant snippet of your UI code and your approach so far. [mcve] Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54641163/edit) link below your question.

Comment: How does choosing a value in dropdowns in the UI have anything to do with Node.js?

Comment: I am setting short and country to dropdown fields through mongoose schema. This is working fine. Now if I select 'IN' from short, 'India' should get selected in country.
$(function() {
 $('#short').on('change',function(){
 var short = $('#short').val();
 //var short = $('#short').find(":selected").text();
 alert(short);
   //$('#country').val()="India";  -- here I want to set value of country dropdown based on short value...if short is IN, country should be India
 });
});

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
  $('#country').change(function() {
    const state = $('#state');
    state.empty();
    if (this.value) {
      getStates(this.value).then(function (states) {
        states.forEach(s => { state.append($(`<option>${s}</option>`)); });
      });
    }
  });
  
  function getStates(countryId) {
    // Returning a promise to simulate calling your node back end
    // Non mock should return $.get('states/' + countryId)
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      resolve(
        countryId === '1' ? ['Andhra Pradesh', 'Arunachal Pradesh'] :
        countryId === '2' ? ['New York', 'New Jersey', 'Wasington', 'California'] :
        ['Bedfordshire', 'Berkshire']
      );
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">India</option>
  <option value="2">United States</option>
  <option value="3">United Kingdom</option>
</select><br>

<select id="state">
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but getting ${s} in country dropdown on changing short value. Below is my code:-
$(function() {
 $('#short').change(function(){
 const country = $('#country');
 country.empty();
 if (this.value) {
   getcountry(this.value).then(function (countries) {
  countries.forEach(s => { country.append($('<option>${s}</option>')); });
   });
 }
  });
  function getcountry(short) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   resolve(
  short === 'IN' ? ['India'] : 
  short === 'US' ? ['United States'] : ['United Kingdom']
   );
 });
  }
});

Comment: following is HTML Code:

<select id="short" name="short">
 <option value="IN">IN</option> 
 <option value="US">US</option> 
 <option value="UK">UK</option> 
</select>
<select id="country" name="country">
</select>
due to size constraint, had to sent in two separate updates